# mkdir on windows - CAKEPHP

Tags: windows, cakephp

Hi I am searching for a good solution since a while and I found nothing to help me on google.

I got an error on my website with the function mkdir, but only when I set the debug at 2.

Here is the error

> Warning (2): mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Invalid argument
>   [CORE\cake\libs\folder.php, line 498]

Im on windows server 2003 and every permission are given to all my folder.

The path that is given to the function is

> C:\Inetpub\vhosts[DOMAIN NAME]\subdomains[SUBDOMAIN
>   NAME]\httpdocs\app\webroot\C:

I notice the last C: at the end of the path but don't know where it come from nor does I know what the function is trying to create.

Comment: does this happen on all your pages or only when you try to access a certain page?

Answer (score 0):

mkdir() should ideally take the path to directory and should not include the file name. The invalid argument warning seems to suggest the same. Try passing the argument without filename.

/Thanks.